# Is there any way to know that gzip compressed byte[] has been compressed more than once in java?

Tags: java, compression, netty, reactor-netty

I am using io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecompressor to decompress the gzip compressed request in my spring boot application server and its decompressing it fine. However when client send me 2 times compressed request body(by mistake) then netty HttpContentDecompressor could decompress it only once and request body was still compressed. So my downstream application started getting failed as they had assumption that they will only get the decompressed data.
Is there any way to know that receiving byte[] has been fully compressed or still decompressed?

Comment: What if the original data was itself the result of gzip compression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gzip`ed files contain well-known header bytes

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip

> a 10-byte header, containing a magic number (1f 8b), the compression method (08 for DEFLATE), 1-byte of header flags, a 4-byte timestamp, compression flags and the operating system ID.

After your first decompression, check to see if `1f 8b` is present.

Aside, if you are accepting files for processing and the file type is important, it's good practice to validate the restricted sets of files.

Comment: The only catch is that a file *could* start with 10 bytes that look like a GZIP header, and not be a real GZIP file.  It is highly unlikely to happen by accident ... but it is possible ... and it is also possible that this might be done deliberately.  My advice would be to NOT try to do the decompression twice.  Instead report this as an error.

Comment: @Possum I am getting data in byte[] as below, can we check this 1f 8b in this byte[]?

[31, -117, 8, 8, 64, 125, 50, 100, 0, 3, 114, 101, 113, 117, 101, 115, 116, 46, 116, 120, 116, 0, 125, 82, -53, 78, -61, 48, 16, -68, 35, -15, 15, 85, -49, 52, 114, -102, -40, 121, -36, -46, 23, -118, 68, -117, -60, -29, -124, 56, -72, -50, 38, -75, 72, 108, -53, 113, -118, 10, -30, -33, -79, -109, 80, -32, 0, 114, 46, -50, -52, -84, 103, 103, -9, -3, -14, 98, 50, -103, -74, -99, -30, -73, -6, -66, 99, 124, -102, 78, -90, -68, 105, -7, 108, 30, -124, -56, -57, 73, +339 more]

Comment: @StephenC, totally agreed with you, we will not be doing decompression twice but wanted to know that data (byte[]) we are getting is still compressed!

Comment: @Vaibhav - don't you know how to convert a signed decimal byte value to unsigned hexadecimal?

Comment: @possum , how to check if compressed byte[] is compressed using BROTLI or DEFLATE as these don't have any header like gzip encoding.